# React Redux mapping over state

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, mapping

I'm working on an app where a user inputs an exercise name and a weight, and then the app will show what the percents of that weight are. I am using redux to store my state. However, I'm having trouble when I am calling it in one of my pages. I can't figure out how to call only the weight of the specific exercise chosen. Right now, my app returns the weight of every exercise added.
Here is the code for my Percent chart (where the issue is):

```
const PercentChart = (props) => {
    const classes = useStyles();
    const [results, setResults] = useState([]);
    const mapWeights = props.weight.map(value => parseInt(value.movementWeight));

        useEffect(() => {
        const arr = [];
        let percentage = 100;
        while (percentage > 50 ) {
            arr.push([percentage, (mapWeights[0] * percentage) / 100]);
            percentage -= 5;
        }
        setResults(arr);
        // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
    }, []);

    const displayWeight = () => {
        if (mapWeights.length === 0) {    
            return <div className={classes.noMovementsMessage} >No 1RM recorded</div> 
        };

        return <div>{mapWeights[0]}</div>
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <div className={classes.oneRepMaxWeight}>One Rep Max: {displayWeight()}</div>   
            <div className={classes.oneRepMaxChart}>
                <h1 className={classes.chartHeader} >Percent<div>Weight</div></h1>
                <div>
                    {results.map((result) => (
                    <div key={result[0]} className={classes.chartBox} >{result[0]}% <div>{result[1]}</div></div>
                    ))}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        weight: state.move,
    }
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(PercentChart);
```

Here is the reducer:

```
const initialState = [];

const addMovementReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case ADD_MOVEMENT: 
            return [ ...state, action.payload ];
        default:
            return state;
    }
};

export default addMovementReducer;
```

So right now if a user for example adds a 'Bench Press' exercise with '300' as the weight, and 'Squat' with '400' as the weight, when I click on the 'Bench Press' button, the One Rep Max div will show both '300' and '400', instead of just '300'.
The result of state.move (for this case) would be and array with two objects:

```
[
 {
  movementName: 'bench',
  movementWeight: '300'
 },
 {
  movementName: 'squat',
  movementWeight: '400'
 }
]
```

Also, the chart gives me an issue of NaN, but that's an issue for another time I guess.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: so where is the reducer code and what is stored in `state.move`?

Comment: @Apostolos I edited the question to include both. If I am missing something else please let me know.

Comment: cant figure it out. can you post a codesandbox in order to work there? i cant see any weird part here.